# Why am I getting "Definition for rule 'import/no-extraneous-dependencies' was not found" when running ESLint?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, electron, babeljs, eslint

I'm working on an Electron app with React and I'm using Typescript, Webpack, Babel and ESLint. And for some reason I get in my **main.js** file, which is my bundled file, the following line:

```
try {
    // Optional dependency (as in, doesn't need to be installed, NOT like optionalDependencies in package.json)
    // eslint-disable-next-line import/no-extraneous-dependencies
    const supportsColor = __webpack_require__(/*! supports-color */ "./node_modules/supports-color/index.js");

    if (supportsColor && (supportsColor.stderr || supportsColor).level >= 2) {
        exports.colors = [
```

Which triggers the following error when I run `npm run lint`:

```
> biomech@1.0.0 lint
> eslint .


/Users/lucas_sg/Documents/pf-biomech/dist/main.js
  2946:2  error  Definition for rule 'import/no-extraneous-dependencies' was not found  import/no-extraneous-dependencies

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)

npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/lucas_sg/Documents/pf-biomech
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c eslint .

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/lucas_sg/.npm/_logs/2021-01-29T22_56_39_247Z-debug.log
```

And when I check out the log I don't feel like I know more about how to debug the error:

```
0 verbose cli [
0 verbose cli   '/usr/local/Cellar/node/15.6.0/bin/node',
0 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
0 verbose cli   'run',
0 verbose cli   'lint'
0 verbose cli ]
1 info using npm@7.4.0
2 info using node@v15.6.0
3 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 2ms
4 timing config:load:file:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/npmrc Completed in 1ms
5 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 1ms
6 timing config:load:cli Completed in 2ms
7 timing config:load:env Completed in 0ms
8 timing config:load:file:/Users/lucas_sg/Documents/pf-biomech/.npmrc Completed in 0ms
9 timing config:load:project Completed in 1ms
10 timing config:load:file:/Users/lucas_sg/.npmrc Completed in 0ms
11 timing config:load:user Completed in 0ms
12 timing config:load:file:/usr/local/etc/npmrc Completed in 0ms
13 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:cafile Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms
16 timing config:load:setUserAgent Completed in 0ms
17 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
18 timing config:load Completed in 8ms
19 verbose npm-session 3273db6630b48789
20 timing npm:load Completed in 16ms
21 timing command:run-script Completed in 1117ms
22 verbose stack Error: command failed
22 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/promise-spawn/index.js:64:27)
22 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:379:20)
22 verbose stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1065:16)
22 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:296:5)
23 verbose pkgid biomech@1.0.0
24 verbose cwd /Users/lucas_sg/Documents/pf-biomech
25 verbose Darwin 20.2.0
26 verbose argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/15.6.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "lint"
27 verbose node v15.6.0
28 verbose npm  v7.4.0
29 error code 1
30 error path /Users/lucas_sg/Documents/pf-biomech
31 error command failed
32 error command sh -c eslint .
33 verbose exit 1
```

My **.eslintrc** file is:

```
{
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 7,
        "sourceType": "module",
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        }
    }
}
```

And my **package.json** in case it's useful:

```
{
  "name": "Electron app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./dist/main.js",
  "preload": "./dist/preload.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "concurrently --success first \"npm run dev:electron\" \"npm run dev:react\" -k",
    "dev:electron": "NODE_ENV=development webpack --config webpack.electron.config.js --mode development && electron .",
    "dev:react": "NODE_ENV=development webpack serve --config webpack.react.config.js --mode development",
    "build:electron": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack.electron.config.js --mode production",
    "build:react": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack.react.config.js --mode production",
    "build": "npm run build:electron && npm run build:react",
    "pack": "electron-builder --dir",
    "dist": "electron-builder",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.+(js|jsx|json|yml|yaml|css|md|vue)\""
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "license": "MIT",
  "build": {
    "files": [
      "dist/",
      "node_modules/",
      "package.json"
    ],
    "productName": "Biomech",
    "appId": "com.example.app",
    "directories": {
      "output": "dist"
    }
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.9.4",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.9.0",
    "@types/electron-devtools-installer": "^2.2.0",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.7",
    "@types/regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.0",
    "dpdm": "^3.6.0",
    "electron": "^11.2.1",
    "electron-builder": "^22.7.0",
    "electron-devtools-installer": "^3.1.1",
    "eslint": "^7.18.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.1",
    "husky": "^4.3.8",
    "lint-staged": "^10.5.3",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "webpack": "^5.11.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.3.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.22",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "chokidar": "^3.5.1",
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "css-loader": "^5.0.1",
    "electron-fetch": "^1.7.3",
    "fsevents": "^2.3.1",
    "ini": "^2.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-google-login": "^5.2.2",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "npm run lint && npm run format"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.+(js|jsx)": "eslint --fix",
    "*.+(json|css|md)": "prettier --write"
  }
}
```

I don't know where the `eslint-disable-next-line import/no-extraneous-dependencies` line is coming from. If it's from Webpack, or Babel, or something else. But I don't think I actually need it since I never even typed a rule regarding extraneous dependencies. I tried adding an empty rule to the **.eslintrc** just so that it would at least make sense but I couldn't find anything regarding **no-extraneous-dependencies** in the ESLint docs, so I could never add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `eslint .` command will run the linting on all the files including the bundled scripts files too. You should add [.eslintignore](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#eslintignore) file and ignore the files on which you wish to run the lint.

In your case ignore add `**/*.js` to tell eslint ignore linting `.js` files.

Comment: Just to check, I should only lint the files I'm coding myself, not the bundled ones by Webpack, right?

Comment: That's right :). You don't have full control over how webpack will build the bundles. If you dive into webpack GitHub repo it adds a lot of `eslint-disable` comments.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this , I simmply ran the following 2 commannds to delete & reinstall my node_modules folder.

`rm -Rf node_modules/.cache`

`npm i`